# Склонение названия образовательного учреждения

Tags: склонение

Как правильно записать в винительном падеже название нашей школы

Муниципальное казенное общеобразовательное учреждение **Першинскую среднюю общеобразовательную школу Киржачского района Владимирской области** 
или 
Муниципальное казенное общеобразовательное учреждение **Першинская средняя общеобразовательная школа Киржачского района Владимирской области**

А если  в кавычках Муниципальное казенное общеобразовательное учреждение "**Першинскую среднюю общеобразовательную школу Киржачского района Владимирской области**"
или 
Муниципальное казенное общеобразовательное учреждение "**Першинская средняя общеобразовательная школа Киржачского района Владимирской области**"

Answer (score 1):

Поступил в муниципальное казенное общеобразовательное учреждение (МКОУ)"Першинская средняя общеобразовательная школа Киржачского района Владимирской области". Название учреждения пишется в кавычках и не склоняется.

Comment: Можно и без кавычек. Тогда склоняется.

Comment: Нет,склоняется БЕЗ родового названия: поступил в Першинскую среднюю общеобразовательную школу Киржачского района Владимирской области, но если есть родовое наименование и имя собственное,родовое название пишется с маленькой буквы, а имя собственное берётся в кавычки и не склоняется.

Comment: где тут кавычки? http://clearspending.ru/customer/03283000166/

Comment: Кавычки надо написать. Если просмотреть подобные названия, то они, как правило, пишутся с кавычками, например: Муниципальное казенное 
общеобразовательное учреждение"Краснологская средняя общеобразовательная школа". В этом случае кавычки выполняют разделительную функцию: отдельно указывается вид собственности и вид деятельности.

Comment: Кристабелл, здесь спрашивают, как правильно писать, а пишут все по-разному, даже так:(с сайта школы) Средняя Общеобразовательная Школа Киржачского Района, Владимирской Области, Поселение Першино, но это не по правилам русского языка Правила здесь:
http://www.profiz.ru/sr/7_2008/pravila_napisania_oficial/ 
http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters?rub=kav2

Comment: Обратите внимание: реальные собственные имена тоже могут употребляться в сочетании с родовым наименованием (чаще всего – обозначением организационно-правовой формы) и при этом заключаться в кавычки, но при употреблении без родового наименования они, в отличие от условных названий, пишутся без кавычек, ср.: Московская типография № 2 и ОАО «Московская типография № 2», Государственная академия славянской культуры и образовательное учреждение «Государственная академия славянской культуры»,

Answer (score 0):

1й вариант, конечно.